# Discord.js bot not replying

Tags: discord

I just started learning how to build a bot in JavaScript and I don't understand why my bot isn't replying to my message.
It has the Administrator role and it should be reading the message in chat.
What seems to be the problem here?

Thank you

```
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js")
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const TOKEN = "..."

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "sup"){
        message.reply("Hello World!")
    }
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You sent `sup` in the chat, verbatim, right?

Comment: Try writing `async` before `(message)`. So something like `client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {`. Does that work?

Comment: @RyanZhang I have sent "sup" yes. I've also tried adding "async" but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Discord.js v14

You need the [`MessageContent`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents:%7E:text=1%20%3C%3C%2014)%0A%20%20%2D%20TYPING_START-,MESSAGE_CONTENT,-(1%20%3C%3C%2015)%20**%0A%0AGUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS) intent as well.

```js
{
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent ]
}
```

If after this you get an error saying

```js
Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted
```

Than you have to follow these steps :

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

**Make sure to not forget the last button as it is the most important of all 3.**

Comment: It doesn't seem to work after I added the MessageContent, it gives me an error saying "Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted"

Comment: Here I added what to do when you get this error.

Comment: Perfect, I followed the steps and it worked. Thanks a lot!